# JQuery: AJAX Not Working After Getting Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to send and get the data back from server via AJAX, and perform some HTML changes after that with the data obtained. However, after the server process the data and send the result back, AJAX is not displaying the data on the browser. When I `console.log` after the `done` part in AJAX, I can see that it is not working. I tried searching for answers but none are specific to my problem.

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/main/home",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json",
      data: JSON.stringify(//....some data here...)
  }).done(function(result){
      //This console.log doesn't show up. 
      console.log("Result is back");
      console.log(result)
  })
```

**NodeJS/Express**

```
router.post("/main/home", function(req, res){
      //This console.log shows up.
      console.log("Data received");
      res.render("ajaxSnippets/mainHome"); 
      //This also shows up.
      console.log("Data sent back");
});
```

Comment: No one here knows what your functions `updateMainPagePosts` and `removeTextFromInput` are doing ... Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the traffic window in something like Chrome dev tools and seeing if your `POST` request even goes out to the server and whether it is ever returned?

Comment: @CBroe Those functions are not relevant to the question since I am concerned about receiving the data. Anyway, I have removed them to avoid confusion.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Yes the POST data did go out since the server `console.log` did print out. But I am not sure how to check whether it is returned. Could you show me how to check if the data is received in the browser?

Comment: I think it's working now. After I remove `dataType: "json"`, then the browser's console shows up the result. Thanks!